# How to test angular decorator functionality

Tags: angularjs, testing, angularjs-decorator

I have a decorator in Angular that is going to extend the functionality of the $log service and I would like to test it, but I don't see a way to do this. Here is a stub of my decorator:

```js
angular.module('myApp')
  .config(function ($provide) {

    $provide.decorator('$log', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
      var _debug = $delegate.debug;
      $delegate.debug = function() {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);

        // Do some custom stuff

        window.console.info('inside delegated method!');
        _debug.apply(null, args);
      };
      return $delegate
    }]);

  });
```

Notice that this basically overrides the `$log.debug()` method, then calls it after doing some custom stuff. In my app this works and I see the `'inside delegated method!'` message in the console. But in my test I do not get that output.

**How can I test my decorator functionality??**
Specifically, how can I inject my decorator such that it actually decorates my `$log` mock implementation (see below)?

Here is my current test (mocha/chai, but that isn't really relevant):

```js
describe('Log Decorator', function () {
  var MockNativeLog;
  beforeEach(function() {
    MockNativeLog = {
      debug: chai.spy(function() { window.console.log("\nmock debug call\n"); })
    };
  });

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(function() {
    angular.mock.module(function ($provide) {
      $provide.value('$log', MockNativeLog);
    });
  });

  describe('The logger', function() {
    it('should go through the delegate', inject(function($log) {
      // this calls my mock (above), but NOT the $log decorator
      // how do I get the decorator to delegate the $log module??
      $log.debug();
      MockNativeLog.debug.should.have.been.called(1);
    }));
  });
});
```

Comment: But the idea (if I am not mistaken) is that you decorate your `$log` and then you override the entire `$log` with a mock. So obviously in your test you will have a function with a simple `debug` function. I guess I missed something along the way.

Comment: I created a plunker for you, I had to hack a little bit for angular-mock, but check it out: http://plnkr.co/edit/kim2NTNBp0eflOhFVhF3?p=preview

Comment: Also started making a plunker. Note that the call to `angular.module()` needs _two_ arguments...

Comment: Plunk using Angular JS 1.2.x, Angular Mocks for Mocha, Mocha, Chai, and Chai Spies: http://j.mp/1p8AcLT

Comment: Interesting thoughts all. Thanks! I'll take a look and see what I can get going. Also, @al-the-x, in my code that decorator is in it's own file, so no need for the second arg on `angular.module()`, but good catch anyway!

Comment: @jakerella Makes sense; didn't think of that. Please see full answer and v2 in my plunk for the code solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the attached plunk (http://j.mp/1p8AcLT), the initial version is the (mostly) untouched code provided by @jakerella (minor adjustments for syntax). I tried to use the same dependencies I could derive from the original post. Note `tests.js:12-14`:

```js
angular.mock.module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('$log', MockNativeLog);
});
```

This completely overrides the native `$log` Service, as you might expect, with the `MockNativeLog` implementation provided at the beginning of the tests [because `angular.mock.module(fn)` acts as a config function for the mock module](http://j.mp/1p8G3AS). Since the config functions execute in FIFO order, this function clobbers the decorated `$log` Service.

One solution is to re-apply the decorator *inside* that config function, as you can see from version 2 of the plunk (permalink would be nice, Plunker), `tests.js:12-18`:

```js
angular.mock.module('myApp', function ($injector, $provide) {
    // This replaces the native $log service with MockNativeLog...
    $provide.value('$log', MockNativeLog);
    // This decorates MockNativeLog, which _replaces_ MockNativeLog.debug...
    $provide.decorator('$log', logDecorator);
});
```

That's not enough, however. The decorator @jakerella defines *replaces* the `debug` method of the `$log` service, causing the later call to `MockNativeLog.debug.should.be.called(1)` to fail. The method `MockNativeLog.debug` is no longer a spy provided by `chai.spy`, so the matchers won't work.

Instead, note that I created an additional spy in `tests.js:2-8`:

```js
var MockNativeLog, MockDebug;

beforeEach(function () {
    MockNativeLog = {
        debug: MockDebug = chai.spy(function () {
            window.console.log("\nmock debug call\n");
        })
    };
});
```

That code could be easier to read:

```js
MockDebug = chai.spy(function () {
    window.console.log("\nmock debug call\n");
});

MockNativeLog = {
    debug: MockDebug
};
```

And this still doesn't represent a good testing outcome, just a sanity check. That's a relief after banging your head against the "why don't this work" question for a few hours.

Note that I additionally refactored the decorator function into the global scope so that I could use it in `tests.js` without having to redefine it. Better would be to refactor into a proper Service with `$provider.value()`, but that task has been left as an exercise for the student... Or someone less lazy than myself. :D

Comment: I see how this will work now... but yes, having a global decorator function is not ideal. :) I'll work on extracting that to a service.

Comment: Well, I can get this working with the global object, but not the service. Argh. I keep getting `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: LogDecorator`. Anyway, thanks for the other help, I'll see what I can do about it being a service another time.

Comment: @jakerella Since this is being used in a config function, you'd probably have to use `$provider.provider()`, actually, now that I think about it... Or maybe just `$provider.constant()`.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up having to do that in other places as well, but those were for circular references.

Comment: sure, don't thank me, i just can't stand it if one space is out of place, or if i see non-highlighted code... thanks for that answer though - this has been bugging me for a while, too.